# Method must have a return type on an InitializeComponent() method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the partial public class

```
namespace BugNetWPF
{
    public partial class ReportScreen_IdRangeReport : Page
    {
        public GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

The error is saying that the method must have a return type, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: GenerateReport is a constructor to a class with a different name?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the `GenerateReport` constructor from somewhere else and forget to change the name to `ReportScreen_IdRangeReport`? Constructor names must match their respective class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What everyone else is saying about the return type is true, but I'm guessing this is what you actually want:

```
namespace BugNetWPF
{
    public partial class ReportScreen_IdRangeReport : Page
    {
        public ReportScreen_IdRangeReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor needs to have the same name as the class.

Comment: That was my guess as well, the poster is the only one who knows.

Comment: when I do this I get the error message ('ReportScreen_IdRangeReport': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type) I have added a void to the class and this works but is this the best thing to do? as you can tell from the question I am very new to WPF and not that advanced in c# so i'm sorry if i'm coming across as stupid

Comment: @Lloyd Did you do both at the same time? As in `public void ReportScreen_IdRangeReport`? You should either add `void` or change the name to match the name of the class, not both.

Comment: exactly that @Magnus! Thanks for the help! its working as expected now thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
        public GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }
```

on:

```
    public void GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

If your `GenerateReport` method doesn't return anything the return type should be declared as `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided a constructor called `GenerateReport` to class `ReportScreen_IdRangeReport`, constructor must match class

```
namespace BugNetWPF
{
    public partial class ReportScreen_IdRangeReport : Page
    {
        public ReportScreen_IdRangeReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace BugNetWPF
{
    public partial class GenerateReport : Page
    {
        public GenerateReport (MainWindow mainWindow)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `GenerateReport` method doesn't declare a return type. If it doesn't return anything the return type should be declared as `void`.

```
    public void GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally call InitializeComponent in your constructor. Like

```
 public ReportScreen_IdRangeReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Then Your method (`if you really need this` i doubt that)

```
public GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
```

doesn't have a return type and it isn't allowed.

It should have a return type of `void` if you don't want to return anything.

```
public void GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

See *void* in front of your method name:

```
namespace BugNetWPF
{
    public partial class ReportScreen_IdRangeReport : Page
    {
        public void GenerateReport(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```